# How do I remove this driver?

Tags: wireless, drivers, uninstall, realtek-wireless

I found a driver for my wireless adapter, but for some reason, it hasn't worked correctly and I have been having a lot of issues. I'll show you the code I put into the terminal to install it. How do I uninstall it?

```
sudo apt-get install git

git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git

cd rtlwifi_new

make

sudo make install
```

That's it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is quite easy to uninstall. You need to `cd` to the directory where the source is installed.

If you cloned it to your Home folder, then the command is

```
cd rtlwifi_new
```

Then run

```
sudo make uninstall
```